# Why was the Diffy family surprised that Lloyd knows Keely's name?

Tags: plot-explanation, phil-of-the-future

In the series finale episode of *Phil of the Future* (S02E22), Keely enters while the Diffy family is having dinner. Lloyd greets Keely 'Hey, Keely' everyone seems to be surprised that he knows her name. In the past, he has called Keely by her name many times.

Why would they be surprised? Lloyd hasn't mispronounced Keely's name before in the series.